# In Debezium, all records are coming as op: "r". How can I overcome this situation?

Tags: sql-server, debezium, cdc

I want to capture only the inserted records using Debezium by enabling the CDC feature on SQL Server, but all the records are coming with the status "r". When I use a condition like transform op: "c", no records are retrieved. Checking the CDC records on SQL Server, I can see that insert statuses are distinguished, but since they all come with the status "r", I am unable to differentiate the inserted records. How can I overcome this situation?

Connector:

```
{
    "name": "account-activity-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "127.0.0.1",
        "database.port": "50516",
        "database.user": "xx",
        "database.password": "xxxx",
        "database.names": "xxxdb",
        "database.trustServerCertificate": true,
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "xxx",
        "decimal.handling.mode": "double",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schemahistory",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "snapshot.mode": "initial",
        "skipped.operations": "u,d,r",
        "topic.prefix": "data-transfer",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "include.schema.changes": "false",
        "transforms":"unwrap", 
        "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.add.fields":"op",
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode":"rewrite",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones":"false"
    }
}
```

Debezium Records:

```
{
    "Id": "5E4AB241-8091-4FA7-AEF3-08DB6CC9CC08",
    "TenantId": "212B4D87-C910-427B-A2EB-0E1CBBA5B43B",
    .....
    "__op": "r",
    "__deleted": "false"
}
```

I need to receive only the records that are inserts for it to work, but all records are coming with the status "r" regardless of their actual status. This makes it difficult for me to distinguish the records that are inserts.

Comment: Maybe the connector's getting into a funny state due to use of `"skipped.operations": "u,d,r"`? If you check the [skipped.operations documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-property-skipped-operations) it expects the delimited items to contain combinations of `c`, `u`, `d` and `t`. `r` ops are for snapshots and aren't something you can add to that list (at least according to the documentation).

Comment: Even when I don't use the 'skipped.operations' parameter, I end up with the same result. It seems like this parameter has no relation to this situation @AlwaysLearning